# ActiveModel::Dirty watch only specific fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not 100% sure about why `ActiveModel::Dirty` has its name. I'm guessing it is because it *is* considered as *dirty* to use it.

But in some cases, it is not possible to avoid watching on specific fields.

Ex:

```
if self.name_changed?
  self.slug = self.name.parameterize
end
```

Without `ActiveModel::Dirty`, the code would look like:

```
if old_name != self.name
  self.slug = self.name.parameterize
end
```

which implies having stored `old_name` before, and it is not readable, so IMHO, it is *dirtier* than using `ActiveModel::Dirty`. It becomes even worse if `old_number` is a number and equals `params[:user]['old_number']` as it needs to be correctly formated (parsed as int), whereas ActiveRecord does this automagically.

So I would find clean to define watchable fields at Model level:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  watchable_fields :name

  before_save :generate_slug, if: name_changed?

  def generate_slug
    self.slug = self.name.parameterize
  end

end
```

Or (even better?) at controller level, before assigning new values:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.watch_fields(:name)

  @user.assign_attributes(params[:user])

  @user.generate_slug if @user.name_changed?
  @user.save # etc.
end
```

The good thing here is that it removes the memory overload produced by using `ActiveModel::Dirty`.

So my question is:

Can I do that using ActiveRecord pre-built tools, or should I write a custom library to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have ended up doing. I like it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :watched

  def field_watch(field_name)
    self.watched ||= {}
    self.watched[field_name] = self.send(field_name)
    return self
  end

  def field_changed?(field_name)
    self.send(field_name) != self.watched(field_name)
  end
end
```

And in the controller

```
def update
  @user = current_user.field_watch(:name)
  @user.assign_attributes(params[:user])
  @user.generate_slug if @user.field_changed?(:name)
  @user.save
end
```

I'll report here if I take the time to wrap this code in a gem or something.

Answer (score 1):

If `ActiveModel::Dirty` solves your problem, feel free to use it. The name comes from the term "dirty objects" and is not meant to imply that it's a dirty/hackish module.
See this answer for more details on dirty objects: [What is meant by the term "dirty object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745888/what-is-meant-by-the-term-dirty-object)

Comment: Interesting. Though it still generates the memory overload, doesn't it? I mean, it makes sense to track some fields, but others not.

Comment: Im sure there's some overhead but it's probably irrelevant unless you got very, very strict memory requirements.